# How to convert values from characters to numbers

Tags: pascal

How to convert letters into numbers.
Let's say A:=5 and B:=10.
When the input is AB, i want the output result to be A+B (510)
I'm going to do this with all characters in alphabet.

Comment: In what number system is A = 5 and B = 10? How are you getting the "input"? You're going to need to be a lot more specific if we're to be able to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will lead you to a complete solution:

```
program ccn;
const
  a= 'A';
  z= 'Z';
type
  domain= a..z;
var
  conv:  array[ domain] of integer;
  input: string;
  i: integer;

begin
conv[ 'A'] :=  5;
conv[ 'B'] := 10;
{ ...more}

input := 'AB';
writeln( 'input:', input);
write( 'output:');
for i := 1 to length( input)
do
   write( conv[ input[ i]]);

writeln;
end.
```

Answer (score -1):

i am not a pascal specialist, but this should work:

get the  ordinal number of each letter with

```
n:=ord(s)
```

then you can substract the Ord of the ascii "A" of it and add 10 if you wish to have 10 for A 11 for B etc;

in case you want to map the letters to your own numbers you could  use an array instead which contains 5 at the index corresponding to the ordinal posisition of "A", 10 at position of B, etc.

then apply

```
str()
```

to each resulting n

then use

```
+
```

or

```
concat()
```

to put the strings together

Comment: sorry have no time for that- just a general direction here. you could try to google each of the functions i mentioned and clip together the provided examples as a start

Comment: just out of curiosity, who was voting my answer down and why?